# Creating a custom Lint Java Detector

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, lint, android-lint

I'm trying to create a custom rule for Lint that would be a twist on existing deprecation warning tests.

Thing is the documentation I have read so far tells me really little about how to implement a class (that I think needs to be) implementing Detector.JavaScanner

http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-custom-rules

This is a fairly general question I guess, but anyone knowledgeable of this issue, or where I could find actually useful documentation on the matter?

Thanks!

Comment: See my question on this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40133113/writing-custom-lint-warning-to-check-for-custom-annotation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Documentation on this is really rare, so don't worry if you haven't found more.

The best way to start into custom lint rule development is actually **to adapt existing rules** like mentioned [here](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint/writing-a-lint-check).

Here are the sources of Android's default set of rules: Pick one that implements [`JavaScanner`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/master/lint/cli/src/test/java/com/android/tools/lint/checks) to see how it works.

If you are looking for a basic, gradle-based, project template for your custom rules, please take a look at [one custom rule](https://github.com/a11n/AndroidLintPlaceholderCheck) I have created. Just replace the `HardcodedValueDetector` with your detector and reference it in the `CustomIssuesRegistry`.

One last remark: I hold a workshop at Droidcon 2015 in Berlin, where I elaborated on how to write custom lint rules. One part was on [JavaScanners](https://15.droidcon.de/session/custom-lint-rules-improve-your-code-quality-dedicated-conventions). I am going to publish all sources after that workshop.

Comment: Great resources, thanks! I managed to work around that issue but I'll be sure to check out all that sweet documentation.

Comment: The 4th link doesn't work anymore, can you post an updated one?

Comment: Updated. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: @Jun try to remove "s" in URL (I mean use http only).

Comment: Seems like a great answer but some of the links are dead now. Can anyone summarize `JavaScanner`?